# unable to debug remote application on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug using eclipse on e remote j2ee application deployed on websphere, the debug configuration is enabled on the server console, but that doesn't work, it take a long time to establish a connection, then i got the following exceptions on the error log.

[image: **Websphere debug configuration :**]

[image: **Thread stack**]

[image: **error log**]

Comment: Check whether any firewall in between or problem with proxy setting.

Comment: firewall is disabled, how to check proxy settings ?

Comment: Are your all request go through a proxy? If so you have to configure your ip in the proxy setting.

Comment: i tried debugging on other platforms using solaris and windows, in the same network , without any proxy settings, it worked , but not for this specific platform :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by upgrading the websphere version from 7.0.0 to 7.0.31